# Como fazer uma seleção com javascript

Tags: javascript

Como selecionar test8 do post que cliquei??

```js
var black = document.querySelectorAll(".test4");

for(var i = 0; i < black.length; i++){
  black[i].addEventListener("click", selectRoxo);
}

function selectRoxo(){
  // Como selecionar test8 do post que cliquei??
  
  
}
```

```css
.posts{
 width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.coluna1, .coluna2{
  width: 90px;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
}
.la, .lo{
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.test4{
 background: black;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.test8{
  background: purple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="posts">
 <div class="coluna1">
      <div class="test1 la"></div>
      <div class="test2 la"></div>
      <div class="test3 la"></div>
      <div class="test4 la">Clicar</div>
  </div>
   <div class="coluna2">
      <div class="test5 lo"></div>
      <div class="test6 lo"></div>
      <div class="test7 lo"></div>
      <div class="test8 lo">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="posts">
 <div class="coluna1">
      <div class="test1 la"></div>
      <div class="test2 la"></div>
      <div class="test3 la"></div>
      <div class="test4 la">Clicar</div>
  </div>
   <div class="coluna2">
      <div class="test5 lo"></div>
      <div class="test6 lo"></div>
      <div class="test7 lo"></div>
      <div class="test8 lo">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar `parentNode` e `querySelector` para chegar até a `div` desejada, mas é preciso alterar o `eventListener` para passar o elemento clicado como parâmetro para a função:

```js
var black = document.querySelectorAll(".test4");

for(var i = 0; i < black.length; i++){
   black[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ selectRoxo(this) });
}

function selectRoxo(e){
  
  var test8 = e.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".coluna2 .test8");
  
  console.log(test8);
  
}
```

```css
.posts{
 width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.coluna1, .coluna2{
  width: 90px;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
}
.la, .lo{
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.test4{
 background: black;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.test8{
  background: purple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="posts">
 <div class="coluna1">
      <div class="test1 la"></div>
      <div class="test2 la"></div>
      <div class="test3 la"></div>
      <div class="test4 la">Clicar</div>
  </div>
   <div class="coluna2">
      <div class="test5 lo"></div>
      <div class="test6 lo"></div>
      <div class="test7 lo"></div>
      <div class="test8 lo">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="posts">
 <div class="coluna1">
      <div class="test1 la"></div>
      <div class="test2 la"></div>
      <div class="test3 la"></div>
      <div class="test4 la">Clicar</div>
  </div>
   <div class="coluna2">
      <div class="test5 lo"></div>
      <div class="test6 lo"></div>
      <div class="test7 lo"></div>
      <div class="test8 lo">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: vlw, me ajudou!

Comment: De nada amigo. Não esqueça de marcar ✓ na resposta que vc achou melhor. Vi aqui que vc nunca marca rs... isso não é interessante para a comunidade. Procure sempre escolher uma resposta para as suas perguntas e marque ✓ em apenas uma delas. Abs!

Comment: uai eu marco setinha pra cima, tem outro lugar para qualificar?

Comment: Abaixo da setinha tem um símbolo cinza ✓

Comment: Ao clicar nela ele fica verde, mas vc só deve fazer isso em apenas 1 resposta, a que vc achou melhor... votar (setinhas) vc pode votar em quantas quiser

Comment: Vc não é obrigado a marcar quando nenhuma resposta resolveu ou ajudou de alguma forma, mas isso geralmente é raro

Comment: Isso é explicado na página do [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)... é bom dar uma olhada

Comment: Valeu! Depois revise todas as suas perguntas e marque a melhor resposta de cada uma... todas elas estão sem resposta escolhida. Abs amigo!

Answer (score 0):

pode tentar asssim chamando um evento na linha clicada e passando this que vai pegar objeto em questão obter e uma função que vai ser chamada usa console log

```
<div class="test8 lo" onclick="obter(this)">8</div>

function obter(obj){
 console.log(obj)
}
```

Comment: Não, assim nao da, porque quero clicar no preto!